# Is this list garbage memory?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have two class like this:

**foo.h**

```
class A //base class
{
public:
    A(QList<int> &timers, QList<int> &positions);
    int pIndex = 0;
    QList<int> timers;
    QList<int> positions;
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    B();
private:
    QList<int> t { 5, 8, 10, 20, 25 };
    QList<int> p { 10, 15, 20 };
};
```

foo.cpp

```
B::B()
    : A(t, p)
{
}

A::A(QList<int> &t, QList<int> &p)
{
    foreach (int v, t) {
       qDebug() << "v = " << v;
    }

    //this->timers = t;
    //this->positions = p;
}
```

but when I intitialize B class, it crashes saying about SGIFAULT.

```
auto b = new B();
```

What am I missing for get this error? at first I thought it was the QList that I pass passing that had become garbage memory at time but this code which follow same principle but use an `int[]` rather `QList<int>` does work fine:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int p[3]) 
    {
        this->v = p;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            printf("v = %d\n", v[i]);
        }
    }
private:
    int *v = NULL;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A(values) 
    {
    }
private:
    int values[3] = {1, 2, 3};
};

int main() {
    A *o = new B();
    o->print();
}
```

Comment: Try using valgrind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, `t` and `p` are not constructed yet when you call base class constructor:

Check this out (`static` members are constructed before any class object is created, note this might not be the solution you are looking for):

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B();
private:
    static QList<int> t;
    static QList<int> p;
};

QList<int> B::t { 5, 8, 10, 20, 25 };
QList<int> B::p { 10, 15, 20 };
```

Now it compiles and outputs

```
5
8
10
20
25
```

Also, you didn't pass second `QList` to base class constructor.

Alternative version:

```
class A
{
public:
    //const references
    A(const QList<int> &timers, const QList<int> &positions);
    int pIndex = 0;
    QList<int> timers;
    QList<int> positions;
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    B();
private:
    // no need for QList members
};


B::B()
    : A({ 5, 8, 10, 20, 25 }, { 10, 15, 20 }) // use initializer lists directly
{
}

A::A(const QList<int> &t, const QList<int> &p)
{
    for (int v : t) {
       qDebug() << "v = " << v;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto b = new B();
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: I can't mark `p` and `t` as static members. Is there an alternative to pass it at constructor time? I'm not passing the second, this was a mistake when I made a minimal code example to post here on SO

Comment: @Jack. If you look carefully, you might see that you have 2 exact duplicates of each `QList`. You might just omit creating `QList` objects in `B` class, and pass values directly to `A` constructor. But remember to make arguments `const` references.

Comment: By pass value directly to base class you mean like this? `SleepValueHigh::SleepValueHigh()
    : SleepValueDef({ 5, 8, 10, 20, 25 }, {1, 2, 3}) { }` I'd like to have this values still as variables members of the class. Maybe can I use pointers in the base class to hold the reference of t and p from B class?

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit; sorry. I changed my approach, rather than take `p` and `t` at base class constructor time I did set it in at B constructor time, like this: `B::B() { A::timers = t; A::postions = p; }`. I'm also considering how to remove the duplicate lists... pointer/reference

Comment: I eneded up using two pointers in A class seting them by a method defined in A called from B at constructor time